# How to make the confusion matrix in this case?

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
test <- h2o.importFile(path = "C:/Users/AkshayJ/Documents/newapril/data/testdata.csv")
train <- h2o.importFile(path = "C:/Users/AkshayJ/Documents/newapril/data/traindata.csv")
y <- "Label"
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])
test[,y] <- as.factor(test[,y])
train[,"Allele1Top"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele1Top"])
test[,"Allele1Top"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele1Top"])
train[,"Allele2Top"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele2Top"])
test[,"Allele2Top"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele2Top"])
train[,"Allele1Forward"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele1Forward"])
test[,"Allele1Forward"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele1Forward"])
train[,"Allele2Forward"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele2Forward"])
test[,"Allele2Forward"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele2Forward"])
train[,"Allele1AB"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele1AB"])
test[,"Allele1AB"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele1AB"])
train[,"Allele2AB"] <- as.factor(train[,"Allele2AB"])
test[,"Allele2AB"] <- as.factor(test[,"Allele2AB"])
train[,"Chr"] <- as.factor(train[,"Chr"])
test[,"Chr"] <- as.factor(test[,"Chr"])
train[,"SNP"] <- as.factor(train[,"SNP"])
test[,"SNP"] <- as.factor(test[,"SNP"])
x <- setdiff(names(train),y)
model <- h2o.deeplearning(
x = x,
y = y,
training_frame = train,
validation_frame = test,
distribution = "multinomial",
activation = "RectifierWithDropout",
hidden = c(32,32,32),
input_dropout_ratio = 0.2,
sparse = TRUE,
l1 = 1e-5,
epochs = 10)
predic <- h2o.predict(model, newdata = test)
table(pred=predic, true = test[,21])
```

Everything is fine but the last line
    table(pred=predic, true = test[,21])
gives the error
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  invalid type/length (environment/0) in vector allocation

Comment: Reopen reason: while the code example isn't minimal (nor reproducible, as the data wasn't included) it was enough to understand the question, and be able to answer it.

Comment: Akshay, for a classification problem (like this), using the iris data set is often good (h2o has no problem detecting column types in the iris data, either, so no need to clutter your minimal code with `as.factor()` lines).

Comment: okay...will keep this in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function `h2o.confusionMatrix()` to get the confusion matrix. The easy way is to give it the model, and the data you want analyzed:

```
h2o.confusionMatrix(model, test)
```

If you look at `?h2o.confusionMatrix` you see it can also accept an `H2OModelMetrics` object. You get one of those by calling `h2o.performance()`:

```
p = h2o.performance(model, test)
h2o.confusionMatrix(p)
```

I recommend the second way, as the `p` object contains other useful information about how good your model is.

Note: either way you didn't use your predictions. Basically:

- `h2o.performance` if you want to analyze the quality of the model.
- `h2o.predict` if you want to get the actual predictions.

Comment: I tried both ways, but I get the same output: a confusion matrix, with same values, error, and threshold. Why you prefer the second way(`h2o.confusionMatrix(p)`)

Comment: @DavidLeal Because if I print `p` it tells me not just the confusion matrix, but also MSE, RMSE, Logloss, hit ratios, etc. It is also the parameter you give to the individual functions, such as `h2o.mse(p)`.